# each loop returns undefined results

Tags: javascript, jquery

`console.log(data)` output:

```
Object {pid: 1, sibof: "140522864XGHA", naziv: "Kovačič Jože", avrsta: "Televizija"}
```

When i try to output the individual value, it returns ***undefined***.

```
if (data) {

    console.log(data);

    var s_stnaloga;
    var s_sibof;
    var s_stranka;
    var s_blago;
    var count = 0;

    $.each(data, function (i, e) {


        s_stnaloga = e.pid;
        s_sibof = e.sibof;
        s_stranka = e.naziv;
        s_blago = e.avrsta;

        count++;

    });

    console.log(s_sibof);
    console.log(count);

} else {

    console.log('no results');
}
```

**Complete console output:**

```
Object {pid: 1, sibof: "140522864XGHA", naziv: "Kovačič Jože", avrsta: "Televizija"} 
undefined
4
```

Comment: `data` is not an array, it's just a single object. Why are you using `$.each`?

Comment: ^^^ `var s_stnaloga = data.pid` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `each` you iterate through object own properties with `i` as keys and `e` as values:

```
$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    // 'i' will have keys, i.e. '"pid"', '"sibof"', etc.
    // 'e' will have values, i.e. '1', '"140522864XGHA"', etc.
});
```

... resulting `count` to be 4 at the end (by the number of properties in `data` object).

However since `data` is an object itself (not an array of objects!), and you just pick the property values from it, you shouldn't use `each` at all:

```
s_stnaloga = data.pid;
s_sibof = data.sibof;
s_stranka = data.naziv;
s_blago = data.avrsta;
```

Comment: no issue, in programming we learn new everyday and l learn new things everyday from the questions and answers on stackOverflow..:)

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is a single object, not an array, you don't need a loop.

```
var s_stnaloga = data.pid;
var s_sibof = data.sibof;
var s_stranka = data.naziv;
var s_blago = data.avrsta;
```